# Nginx, SiginalR and FastCGI with mono: No application found

Tags: mono, nginx, fastcgi, signalr

I'm trying to get a setup running with all these and I'm failing so hard right now. I mostly want to test Websockets, and since IIS 7.5 doesn't support them, I'm trying to set it up with Nginx and Mono/FastCGI.

So, everything is Windows based, no linux, no unix: windows. Right now, all I'm getting from calling http://localhost:7171/app (or http://127.0.0.1:7171/app) is this error:

> ```
> No Application Found
>
> Unable to find a matching application for request:
>
> Host  localhost:7171
> Port  7171
> Request Path  /app/index.html
> Physical Path C:\nginx\html/app/index.html
> ```

Here are the configs right now:

fastcgi.conf

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

fastcgi_params

```
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;

fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO          "";
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

nginx.conf

```
server {
listen       7171;
server_name  127.0.0.1;


#charset koi8-r;

#access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

location / {

    #fastcgi_index index.html;
    #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #include C:\\nginx\\conf\\fastcgi_params;
 }

location /app {

    fastcgi_index index.html;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    include fastcgi_params;
 }
 }
```

and here's the cmd line used to start fastcgi:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono-2.10.8\bin\fastcgi-mono-server4" /socket=tcp:127.0.0.1:9000 /applications=/:/c://nginx//html//app
```

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It almost work but signalr's scripts (signalr/hubs) are just giving me 404's now. Working on it...

After chatting with the developpers of SignalR, they confirmed that SignalR is not supported by the Nginx+FastCgi mix.

I would recommend to use IIS if you plan to use SignalR. Check their website for more information on SignalR.

Cheers

Comment: Not that it's not supported. It just doesn't fully work in mono yet. The next version of SignalR will support multiple hosts.

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem for anyone who wants to get it to work. It seems that starting fast-cgi-mono-server4 with /application pointing to the absolute path does not work. I had to start it using the relative path:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono-2.10.8\bin\fastcgi-mono-server4" /applications=/:/..\\..\\..\\nginx\\html\\app\\ /socket=tcp:127.0.0.1:9000
```

Also, Nginx can't seem to route location other than /. So you've got to have only one app on the root.

```
location / {
        root c:\\nginx\\html\\app;            
        fastcgi_index index.html;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include C:\\nginx\\conf\\fastcgi_params;
    }
```

It almost work but signalr's scripts (signalr/hubs) are just giving me 404's now. Working on it...

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your tip regarding relative paths saved my time.